# Liferay Elastic Search Query: Search for DLFileEntries that have a Custom Document Type

Tags: elasticsearch, liferay, elasticsearch-query, liferay-7.2

I work with Liferay 7.2 and I need to make an Elasticsearch query that finds als DLFileEntries that have the Document Type "XY". Currently I need to do this in Postman.

I am already able to find all DLFileEntry:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "entryClassName": "com.liferay.document.library.kernel.model.DLFileEntry"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

But I need to find only these DLFileEntry that have Document Type "XY".

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply add another `match` to the field `fileEntryTypeId`, where its value must be equal to the created Document Type id. You can find this id on table `dlfileentrytype` on column `fileentrytypeid`. Considering the id equals `37105`, the query would be like this

```json
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "entryClassName": "com.liferay.document.library.kernel.model.DLFileEntry"
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "fileEntryTypeId": "37105"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

---

edit: Responding to your comment about how to search the `DLFileEntry` by its `DLFileEntryType` name, there is no direct way to do this as the `DLFileEntryType` is not indexed on Elastic Search by default. It would also probably need sub queries to achieve this and Elastic Search doesn't support sub queries.

With that in mind, the easiest approach I can think of is to customize the way `DLFileEntry` is indexed on Elastic Search, adding the field `fileEntryTypeName`. For that, you only need to implement a ModelDocumentContributor for `DLFileEntry` and add the `fileEntryTypeName` field to the document.

Basically, you just need to create a class like this:

```java
package com.test.liferay.override;

import com.liferay.document.library.kernel.model.DLFileEntry;
import com.liferay.portal.kernel.exception.PortalException;
import com.liferay.portal.kernel.search.Document;
import com.liferay.portal.search.spi.model.index.contributor.ModelDocumentContributor;
import org.osgi.service.component.annotations.Component;

@Component(
        immediate = true,
        property = "indexer.class.name=com.liferay.document.library.kernel.model.DLFileEntry",
        service = ModelDocumentContributor.class
)
public class DLFileEntryModelDocumentContributor
        implements ModelDocumentContributor<DLFileEntry> {

    @Override
    public void contribute(Document document, DLFileEntry dlFileEntry) {
        try {
            document.addText(
                    "fileEntryTypeName", dlFileEntry.getDLFileEntryType().getName());
        } catch (PortalException e) {
            // handle error
        }
    }
}
```

As the `DLFileEntryType` name is **localized**, you should probably index it as a localized value:

```java
package com.test.liferay.override;

import com.liferay.document.library.kernel.model.DLFileEntry;
import com.liferay.portal.kernel.exception.PortalException;
import com.liferay.portal.kernel.search.Document;
import com.liferay.portal.kernel.search.Field;
import com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.LocaleUtil;
import com.liferay.portal.search.spi.model.index.contributor.ModelDocumentContributor;
import org.osgi.service.component.annotations.Component;

import java.util.Locale;

@Component(
        immediate = true,
        property = "indexer.class.name=com.liferay.document.library.kernel.model.DLFileEntry",
        service = ModelDocumentContributor.class
)
public class DLFileEntryModelDocumentContributor
        implements ModelDocumentContributor<DLFileEntry> {

    @Override
    public void contribute(Document document, DLFileEntry dlFileEntry) {
        try {
            Locale siteDefaultLocale = LocaleUtil.getSiteDefault();

            String localizedName = dlFileEntry
                    .getDLFileEntryType().getName(siteDefaultLocale);
            String localizedField = Field.getLocalizedName(
                    siteDefaultLocale, "fileEntryTypeName");

            document.addText(localizedField, localizedName);
        } catch (PortalException e) {
            // handle error
        }
    }
}
```

Now your query will be something like this:

```json
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "entryClassName": "com.liferay.document.library.kernel.model.DLFileEntry"
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "fileEntryTypeName_en_US": "XY"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

The name **fileEntryTypeName_en_US** depends on your site default locale. For example, if it is pt_BR, the name would be **fileEntryTypeName_pt_BR**.

Obs.: The `fileEntryType` name field is not unique, as it is localized, so you might find files with the same `fileEntryType` name but different `fileEntryType`.

Comment: Thank you very much!!! This works :)
But I am wondering how can I make this more dynamic, e.g. when I later deploy to production...
So can I get somehow the fileEntryTypeId based on the document type name?